# Postgres: How to create reference cell?

Tags: database, postgresql

In Excel we can create reference cell (e.g. A2 = A1 + 1). Or we create a reference cell on other sheet.

On postgres I would like create a reference cell to another table. Is it possible? How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDBMS uses a different approach. There are *queries* and *data*. When you query something, it is natural to perform extra calculations on the data. In your case this is a simple arythmetic function.

Say, you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id  integer PRIMARY KEY,
  a1  integer
);
```

Now, to achieve your case you can do the following:

```
SELECT id,
       a1,
       a1+1 AS a2
  FROM tab;
```

As you can see, I'm using existing columns in the formula and assign the result a new alias `a2`.

I really recommend you to read the [Tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial.html) and [SQL Basics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql.html) from the official PostgreSQL documentation, along with some SQL introduction book.

Comment: Another option would be to create a view that returns that calculated column.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How about linking a cell to a cell on the other table?